# print character after each line in terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, apt

I'd like to print a \ after each line in a bash script.

Example:
the output of $k is:

```
git-core
nano
apache2
```

Now I want to install this packages using apt. The only solution I now is:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core \
nano \
apache2
```

how do I add this character?

Comment: You already have them in a variable? `sudo apt-get install $k` should work

Comment: I am not so familiar with debian's apt-get. but doesn't `apt-get foo bar baz` work? I mean, separated by space?

Comment: Yes, but they all have to be in one row. Otherwise you have to use a \ at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, you may be looking at the wrong solution for your problem.

You can replace the new line characters from $k with spaces:

```
k=$(echo "$k" | tr '\n' ' ')
```

Better yet, you can take advantage of the bash word parsing, knowing that apt package names don't have spaces in their names (and assuming you are sure all that $k contains are package names, separated by newline):

```
sudo apt-get install $k
```

The lack of quoting for $k will make bash re-parse the newlines into regular word separators (spaces).

If, for some other reason, you **really really** want to add backslash to the end of each line, you can always use sed:

```
echo "$k" | sed 's/$/\\/'
```